# Java:Handling Exception and cant able to input value

Tags: exception

```
package scheme;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnterSchemeDetails {

    private Scanner sc;
public static void main(String []args){
    EnterSchemeDetails schemes=new EnterSchemeDetails();
    schemes.add();
}
public void add() {
    NewEntry newEntry = new NewEntry();
    String newOne = "newrecord";
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter No of Times ");
    int no = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Scheme " + i);
        gettingSchemeDetails(newOne, newEntry);
    }
    boolean condition = displayOption(newEntry);
    if (condition) {
        System.out.println("Stopped Working");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong Input Specify Numeric value ");
        displayOption(newEntry);
    }

}

    public boolean displayOption(NewEntry newEntry) {

        String newOne = null;
        System.out.println("Enter Option ");
        System.out
                .println("1.Display \t 2.Insert \t 3.Update \t 4.Delete \t 5.Exit");
        int option = 0;
        try {
            option = sc.nextInt();

            while (option != 5) {

                if (option == 1) {
                    newEntry.display();
                } else if (option == 2) {
                    newOne = "insert";
                    gettingSchemeDetails(newOne, newEntry);
                } else if (option == 3) {
                    newOne = "update";
                    gettingSchemeDetails(newOne, newEntry);

                } else if (option == 4) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Scheme No to Delete");
                    int schemeNo = sc.nextInt();
                    boolean check = newEntry.deleteOperation(schemeNo);
                    if (check) {
                        System.out.println("Deleted Successfully");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No such Record Found");
                    }

                } else if (option == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Stopped");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                }

                System.out.println("Enter Option ");
                System.out
                        .println("1.Display \t 2.Insert \t 3.Update \t 4.Delete \t 5.Exit");

                option = sc.nextInt();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void gettingSchemeDetails(String newOne, NewEntry newEntry) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int schemeNo = 0;
        if (newOne == "update") {
            System.out.println("Enter Scheme No to Update");
            try {
                schemeNo = sc.nextInt();
                boolean check = newEntry.checkSchemeNo(schemeNo);
                if (check == false) {
                    System.out.println("NO such record found");
                    displayOption(newEntry);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                displayOption(newEntry);

            }

        }
        SchemeInfo bean = new SchemeInfo();

        System.out.println("Enter Scheme Name :");
        bean.setSchemeName(sc.next());
        System.out.println("Enter Fund Name :");
        bean.setFundName(sc.next());
        gettingNavDate(bean);
        try {
            gettingNavAmount(bean);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Input Mismatch enter Numeric value");
            gettingNavAmount(bean);
        }
        try {
            gettingNavUnits(bean);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Input Mismatch enter Numeric value");
            gettingNavUnits(bean);
        }

        gettingCategories(bean);
        if (newOne != "update") {
            newEntry.newRecord(bean);
        } else {
            newEntry.update(schemeNo, bean);
        }
    }

    public void gettingNavDate(SchemeInfo bean) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Nav Date :");
        String navDate = sc.next();

        boolean check = NavDateCheck.checkDateFormat(navDate);
        if (check == true) {
            bean.setNavDate(navDate);

        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Incorrect Date Format..Please Enter Correct Date Format Ex.YYYY-MM-DD");
            gettingNavDate(bean);
        }

    }

    public void gettingNavAmount(SchemeInfo bean) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Schmene Nav Amount :");
        BigDecimal navAmount = new BigDecimal("0");
        navAmount = sc.nextBigDecimal();

        boolean check1 = NavDateCheck.checkNavAmount(navAmount);
        if (check1 == true) {
            bean.setNavAmount(navAmount);

        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Incorrect NavAmount.Enter Correct Nav Amount.Ex.1000.21 ");
            gettingNavAmount(bean);
        }

    }

    public void gettingNavUnits(SchemeInfo bean) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Nav Units :");
        BigDecimal navUnits = new BigDecimal("00");

        navUnits = sc.nextBigDecimal();

        boolean check2 = NavDateCheck.checkNavUnits(navUnits);
        if (check2 == true) {
            bean.setNavUnits(navUnits);

        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Incorrect Nav Units.Enter Correct NavUnits Ex.");
            gettingNavUnits(bean);
        }
    }

    public void gettingCategories(SchemeInfo bean) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Divident Option :");
        bean.setDividentOption(sc.next());
        System.out.println("Enter Scheme Plan Name ");
        bean.setSchemePlanName(sc.next());
        System.out.println("Enter Scheme Category ");
        bean.setSchemeCategory(sc.next());
        System.out.println("Enter Scheme Subcategory");
        bean.setSchemeSubcategory(sc.next());

    }

}
```

I have 2 problems in my code
1.when giving characters/string(other than number) it will throw an exception and i have handled the exception.But second time i cant able to give user input to that option

Enter No of Times 
1
Enter Scheme 1
Enter Scheme Name :
SchemeSample
Enter Fund Name :
FundSample
Enter Nav Date :
1234-12-1
Enter Schmene Nav Amount :
17826
Enter Nav Units :
7328736
Enter Divident Option :
SampleDivident
Enter Scheme Plan Name 
SamplePlaan
Enter Scheme Category 
SampleCategory
Enter Scheme Subcategory
SampleSubCategory
Enter Option 
1.Display    2.Insert    3.Update    4.Delete    5.Exit
f
Wrong Input Specify Numeric value 
Enter Option 
1.Display    2.Insert    3.Update    4.Delete    5.Exit

Comment: Can you express in a better manner?

Comment: problem is..There are only 4 options 1-for Display 2-for Insert 3-for Update 4-Delete 5-for Exit  and i am getting from user input as number if he gives characters(Example:A,if he gives like this) means it will throw exception.After it throws exception user is unable to give input again.